# Select one checkbox and disable others

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to select one checkbox and disable all others. The problem is I am figure out how to do the reverse. Uncheck and enable all checkboxes.

Html:
 This is a dynamic list of checkboxes

```
<input type="checkbox" id="mycheckbox1"/>
<input type="checkbox" id="mycheckbox2"/>
<input type="checkbox" id="mycheckbox3"/>
```

I have tried this:

```
var checkboxlist = $("input:checkbox");

$('.checkbox').on("change", function () {

    var itemId = $(this).attr("id");

    $.each(checkboxlist, function (index, value) {
        var id = $(value).attr("id");

        if (!(itemId === id)) {
            $(value).attr("disabled", "true");
        } 
    });
})
```

Comment: Just to check, your code is now to re-enable the checkboxes? Because you still have `$(value).attr("disabled", "true");` instead of  `$(value).attr("disabled", "false");`

Comment: no, this is the code to disable them, i am looking for help in how I can reverse it by click on same checkbox

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Much simpler to use `not()` inside event handler to target all the others.

Use the `checked` state of current checkbox to determine disabled state

```js
$(':checkbox').change(function(){
     // "this" is current checkbox
     $(':checkbox').not(this).prop('disabled', this.checked);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  
<input type="checkbox" id="mycheckbox1"/>
<input type="checkbox" id="mycheckbox2"/>
<input type="checkbox" id="mycheckbox3"/>
```

Comment: I have managed to do this, what I am after is "once i click the same checkbox again, enable all the rest"

Comment: See update...I figured out your intent and simplified it based on `this.checked`

Comment: I knew there had to be a simpler way, i will accept this

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like for what you are trying to achieve a radio button list may be more appropriate.

```
<input type="radio" name="myRadio" value="myRadio1"/>
<input type="radio" name="myRadio" value="myRadio2"/>
<input type="radio" name="myRadio" value="myRadio3"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var checkboxlist = $("input:checkbox");

    $('.checkbox').on("change", function () {

        var itemId = $(this).attr("id");

        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
          $.each(checkboxlist, function (index, value) {
            var id = $(value).attr("id");

            if (!(itemId === id)) {
                $(value).attr("disabled", "true");
            } 
          });
        } else {
          $.each(checkboxlist, function (index, value) {
            var id = $(value).attr("id");

            if (!(itemId === id)) {
                $(value).attr("disabled", "false");
            } 
          });
        }
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks, there is an error in the snippet does not compile

Comment: ah apologies. Forgot initially to include jQuery